# How get mouse position with ScottPlot 5

Tags: vb.net, scottplot

I am developing a VB .NET program in the VisualStudio 2022 environment and I use the ScottPlot package for generating two-dimensional graphs. In ScottPlot 4 version, it was possible to obtain the coordinates of the mouse position over the graph using the .MouseMove event and the .GetMouseCoordinates() function. Is there a similar option in the ScottPlot 5 package?

I wish to display to the user the coordinates pointed by the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function is not available anymore, therefore I think we can achieve the same thing using the `GetCoordinates` function. You can use it within the MouseMove event:

```
Private Sub CustomMouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim newCoords As ScottPlot.Coordinates = FormPlot1.Plot.GetCoordinates(New ScottPlot.Pixel(e.X, e.Y))
    Label1.Text = newCoords.X.ToString("0.00") + ", " + newCoords.Y.ToString("0.00")
End Sub
```

Alternatively, by creating a function that calculates the mouse position on the control and convert them to coordinates on the plot:

```
Public Function GetMouseCoordinates(ByVal plot As ScottPlot.WinForms.FormsPlot) As ScottPlot.Coordinates
    With FormPlot1.PointToClient(MousePosition)
        Return FormPlot1.Plot.GetCoordinates(New ScottPlot.Pixel(.X, .Y))
    End With
End Function
```